# Pagination Alternatives

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination, jquery-pagination

I am looking for ideas for pagination alternatives. I am aware of 2 pagination schemes:

- Click on pages pagination - [my favorite example](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm)
- Infinite scroll pagination - one implementation [here](http://dzone.com/) that seems to work

There must be some other less known/popular ways to do it. Bonus points if you can provide a link to a demo

Thanks

Comment: Personally I can't stand infinite scroll.

Comment: IMHO pagination is pagination, you can style it different way but the main pourpose is of paginating big amount of results! not sure if paginating with javascript is a good idea if you have a very large results, use php instead! hope this make sense!

Comment: of course i paginate on the server side.

Comment: Is there a script or site that explains how to get the first link pagination?

Comment: ggfan: yes - http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that a good alternative to paging is a way, or more than one way, for the user to tell the server something about what it is they're looking for. For some types of content (like, a whole lot of text, say from a research paper or a work of fiction), of course you're probably stuck with paging. But when the content is naturally searchable (like tables of checking account transactions), good, simple filtering tools are probably more useful than pagination schemes.  (Actually you may need both.)

Answer (score 2):

I worked on a [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) hybrid technique where it did an "infinite scroll" but only showed a "window/page" of information at a time. So it only loaded a fixed amount of data to the browser at any given time. If you could display 20 items and scrolled it just updated the list 20 items at a time. Paging without paging, scrolling without scrolling.

Of course this is a trivial definition of the actual implementation, which was much smarter than this sounds and very optimized for round trips. And this was a list of results that was already filtered down with search criteria. They go hand in hand.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at 'logarithmic' pagination, as described in my answer here:

[How to do page navigation for many, many pages? Logarithmic page navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7835752/999120)

It's like regular pagination, but solves the problem of getting to pages in the middle of a '...' range without many repeated mouseclicks. i.e. How long would it take to get to page 2456 out of 10380 if these are your links: 1 2 3 4 5 ... 10376 10377 10378 10379 10380 ?

(But, Pointy has, uhm... a point also (!))

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for a pure JavaScript pagination control I built recently.  It is similar to your favorite with these added benefits...

- Clicking the ... allows quick jump to any page
- No words means no localization (next, prev, first, last buttons aren't
  needed in this simple control)
- No dependencies (jQuery not required)

```js
var Pagination = {
  code: '',

  Extend: function(data) {
    data = data || {};
    Pagination.size = data.size || 300;
    Pagination.page = data.page || 1;
    Pagination.step = data.step || 3;
  },

  Add: function(s, f) {
    for (var i = s; i < f; i++) {
      Pagination.code += '<a>' + i + '</a>';
    }
  },

  Last: function() {
    Pagination.code += '<i>...</i><a>' + Pagination.size + '</a>';
  },

  First: function() {
    Pagination.code += '<a>1</a><i>...</i>';
  },


  Click: function() {
    Pagination.page = +this.innerHTML;
    Pagination.Start();
  },

  Prev: function() {
    Pagination.page--;
    if (Pagination.page < 1) {
      Pagination.page = 1;
    }
    Pagination.Start();
  },

  Next: function() {
    Pagination.page++;
    if (Pagination.page > Pagination.size) {
      Pagination.page = Pagination.size;
    }
    Pagination.Start();
  },

  TypePage: function() {
    Pagination.code = '<input onclick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);this.focus();" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.blur(); }" value="' + Pagination.page + '" /> &nbsp; / &nbsp; ' + Pagination.size;
    Pagination.Finish();
    var v = Pagination.e.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    v.click();
    v.addEventListener("blur", function(event) {

      var p = parseInt(this.value);

      if (!isNaN(parseFloat(p)) && isFinite(p)) {
        if (p > Pagination.size) {
          p = Pagination.size;
        } else if (p < 1) {
          p = 1;
        }
      } else {
        p = Pagination.page;
      }

      Pagination.Init(document.getElementById('pagination'), {
        size: Pagination.size,
        page: p,
        step: Pagination.step
      });
    }, false);
  },


  Bind: function() {
    var a = Pagination.e.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (+a[i].innerHTML === Pagination.page) a[i].className = 'current';
      a[i].addEventListener('click', Pagination.Click, false);
    }
    var d = Pagination.e.getElementsByTagName('i');
    for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
      d[i].addEventListener('click', Pagination.TypePage, false);
    }
  },

  Finish: function() {
    Pagination.e.innerHTML = Pagination.code;
    Pagination.code = '';
    Pagination.Bind();
  },

  Start: function() {
    if (Pagination.size < Pagination.step * 2 + 6) {
      Pagination.Add(1, Pagination.size + 1);
    } else if (Pagination.page < Pagination.step * 2 + 1) {
      Pagination.Add(1, Pagination.step * 2 + 4);
      Pagination.Last();
    } else if (Pagination.page > Pagination.size - Pagination.step * 2) {
      Pagination.First();
      Pagination.Add(Pagination.size - Pagination.step * 2 - 2, Pagination.size + 1);
    } else {
      Pagination.First();
      Pagination.Add(Pagination.page - Pagination.step, Pagination.page + Pagination.step + 1);
      Pagination.Last();
    }
    Pagination.Finish();
  },


  Buttons: function(e) {
    var nav = e.getElementsByTagName('a');
    nav[0].addEventListener('click', Pagination.Prev, false);
    nav[1].addEventListener('click', Pagination.Next, false);
  },

  Create: function(e) {
    var html = [
      '<a>&#9668;</a>', // previous button
      '<span></span>', // pagination container
      '<a>&#9658;</a>' // next button
    ];
    e.innerHTML = html.join('');
    Pagination.e = e.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
    Pagination.Buttons(e);
  },

  Init: function(e, data) {
    Pagination.Extend(data);
    Pagination.Create(e);
    Pagination.Start();
  }
};

var init = function() {
  Pagination.Init(document.getElementById('pagination'), {
    size: 30, // pages size
    page: 1, // selected page
    step: 2 // pages before and after current
  });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
body:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 1px 2px 4px 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #7D7D7D;
}
#pagination a,
#pagination i {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 22px;
  color: #7D7D7D;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
#pagination a {
  margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#pagination a:hover {
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
}
#pagination i {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#pagination i:hover {
  border: 2px solid #999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#pagination input {
  width: 40px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  color: #7D7D7D;
  text-align: right;
}
#pagination a.current {
  border: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="pagination"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a cool logarithmic pagination solution here:

http://jobcloud.cz/glPagiSmart.jc

But I'm not sure how many people would actually want to use the hex or binary implementations :)